# Bootstrap: gradiant not filling entire page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using LESS with bootstrap and trying to create a simple gradiant but if I use it on the body tag I get a broken gradiant like this image.

http://i.imgur.com/nIyOeQY.png

and if I use it with the html tag I get something like this image (it starts after the div and section tags)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh8FM.png

Here is the code:

```
.bg_gradient(@start-color: @color-grad-top, @end-color: @color-grad-bot) {
background-color:@start-color;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@start-color, @end-color);
background: -o-linear-gradient(@start-color, @end-color);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(@start-color, @end-color);
background: linear-gradient(@start-color, @end-color);
}


html {
height: 100%;
.bg_gradient(@color-grad-top, @color-grad-bot);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to post your HTML as well.

Comment: @potatopeelings the HTML is default bootstrap. its  a simple '<section><div class"container"></div></section>'

Answer (score 0):

I think i might have found the solution, I added the gradient to the html tag and made the body tag's background-color rgba making it transparent. that way the gradient fills the background.